# run a function before Firefox close the window

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

This is my first topic here! So, I'm trying run an ajax function before the Firefox's window close, my code works when I close the tab, but window not. How can I do this?

Detail: Only Firefox don't run the function when window is closed and if possible without use JQuery.

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload',function(event){
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST","index.php",true);
        ajax.send();
    }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)

```
var some_ajax_data; 
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  navigator.sendBeacon('/data.php', some_ajax_data);
};
```